# Cannot retrieve failed tests stacktrace from Bamboo using REST API

Tags: bamboo

I am using bamboo to run E2E Tests (using Selenium). After the build finishes I am using the [Bamboo API](https://developer.atlassian.com/bamboodev/rest-apis/bamboo-rest-resources#BambooRESTResources-BuildService%E2%80%94SpecificBuildResult) to get the build result.
The problem is that the build result doesn't contain any stack trace of the failed tests. I have tried use the URI param `?expand=testResults.failed.testResult.errors` but it only includes an exception message or an assert message.
I need the stacktrace of the exeception too.